# How to select user that doesn't exist in the second table

Tags: mysql

[image]

I am trying to understand how to select a user from **users** table that is not associated with current user in **user_follows** table: neither in **users_id** not in **shown_users_id**.

Basically a new user that not related to my current user.

Tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
   user.id
FROM
   users AS user
LEFT JOIN
   user_follows AS follow ON user.id = follow.users_id
LEFT JOIN 
   user_follows AS follow2 ON user.id = follow2.shown_users_id
WHERE
   user.id != 2 # (user that I don't wan't to select) 
LIMIT 1;
```

But it would still return me the row with user 3 in it.

So if in my **users** table I have user 2,3,4, and with the following data in **user_follows** table:

[image]

I only want to get user 4, since it is not associated with user 2 at this moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 2 anti-joins. Written with either two `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL`:

```
SELECT 
   user.id
FROM
   users AS user
LEFT JOIN
   user_follows AS follower ON  follower.users_id = user.id 
                            AND follower.shown_users_id = 2
LEFT JOIN 
   user_follows AS followed ON  followed.shown_users_id = user.id 
                            AND followed.users_id = 2
WHERE
   follower.users_id IS NULL
  AND
   followed.users_id IS NULL 
  AND
   user.id <> 2 ;
```

or with two `NOT EXISTS` subqueries, which I find far more readable:

```
SELECT 
   user.id
FROM
   users AS user
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM user_follows AS follower
        WHERE follower.users_id = user.id 
          AND follower.shown_users_id = 2
      )
AND
   NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM user_follows AS followed
        WHERE followed.shown_users_id = user.id 
          AND followed.users_id = 2
      ) 
AND
   user.id <> 2 ;
```